# Кластеризация маркеров в api 3.0

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли примеры кластеризации маркеров для api 3.0.

Для предыдущих версий нашёл вот: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create/

Answer (score 1):

Для кластеризации маркеров в yandex api 3.0 используется пакет, который необходимо подключить через импорт

```
const {YMapClusterer, clusterByGrid} = await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-clusterer@0.0.1');
```

Пример использования

```
const clusterer = new YMapClusterer({
    method: clusterByGrid({gridSize: 128}),
    features: map._points,
    функция которая вернет YMapMarker для маркера,
    функция которая вернет YMapMarker для кластера
});
```

Документация по кластеризации есть по этой ссылке:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/ref/packages/clusterer/index.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)